# Present perfect + point of time = simple past

Tags: tense, present-tense

Grammatically,  `present perfect + point of time = simple past.`

> She **has** returned two days ago.
>   (omit "has" to make it correct.)

Similarly:

> She **has** owned this parlour since 2002
>   (it is correct)

As per the above rule, should not we be omitting **"has"** in the second sentence to make it correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The present perfect is a present tense, and the simple past is a past tense, and this is what governs what temporal expressions can be used with each.

- The present perfect can only be used with expressions which **include the present**. That's why you can't say "She has returned two days ago", because *two days ago* is over-and-done-with, it doesn't include the present moment. However, you **can** say "She has owned this parlour since 2002", because *since 2002* designates a timespan which stretches up to the present moment.
- The past can only be used with expressions which **include the past but not the present**; that's why you can't say "I saw him now", because *now* designates a timespan which includes the present. But you **can** say "I saw him **just** now*, because *just now* is taken to designate a moment in the very recent past.

Comment: Having the following: *I can't go out because I broke my leg*. What happens there when there's no time expression, is it still incorrect? I know the perfect tense is used in my example.

Comment: @Subjunctive That's fine with either past or perfect in AmE. Some BrE speakers may be a little uncomfortable with the past.

Comment: As per your example, I believe this sentence is also wrong: This house belongs to me since my birth. (Since my birth is a time span therefore has belonged). Please suggest. Thank you.

Comment: @SeemaBhukar Quite right. Simple present verbs are rare with temporal *since* clauses, because the "present" which the simple present designates itself usually includes any relevant past moment.